# C++ Save/Load double (to/from files)

Tags: c++, double, mingw, standards

[Rewritten for clarity.]

I need to write and read `double`s to and from files, in a format that will always have the same number of characters. The format doesn't need to be human-readable: it just needs to be quick to load (with as little dynamic memory and conversion stuff as possible, file space is important but doesn't matter quite as much).

Is there a standard (or at least safe and reliable) way to get the components of a `double` so that I can store the signicicand sign and mantissa sign as a `'1'` or `'0'` and the significand and mantissa separately in a hex format with a constant length?

Essentially, how can I grab the specific bit/number components from a double? Is it even possible to do this on separate systems (assuming the same OS family such as Windows) or is the standard for the components of `double`s not enforced per OS?

I am using MinGW and of course compiling for Windows. I'd like to use the C Standard Library where possible, not the C++ Standard Library. Also, I'd like to avoid other libraries (like Boost) but if there are specific Windows functions then those would help a lot.

Comment: why you don't just using fstream lib ? you can write and read doubles using fstream

or you want it as componants not whole number ?

Comment: I would much rather use the C standard library than the C++ one. And yes I would rather have the components of the `double` instead of the number written out in one piece.

Comment: "I would much rather use the C standard library than the C++ one" : That being the case, this is tagged C++ ...  *why* exactly?

Comment: By c++ I meant that I'm using the C++ language... but if the tag is misleading I will change it

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way of doing so would be to open your fstream in binary mode, and then use the write() and read() methods of fstream to read your double to/from the stream:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    std::fstream fp( "foo", std::fstream::in |
                            std::fstream::out |
                            std::fstream::trunc |
                            std::fstream::binary );

    double d1, d2;

    d1 = 3.14;

    fp.write( (char*)&d1, sizeof( d1 ) );
    fp.seekg( 0, std::fstream::beg );
    fp.read( (char*)&d2, sizeof( d2 ) );

    std::cout << "d1 = " << d1 << "  d2 = " << d2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a similar approach using cstdio?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want somthing like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
string convertToHex(const T &x)
{
    char *xc = (char *)&x;
    ostringstream s;
    for (char *c = xc; c < xc + sizeof(x); ++c)
        s << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(*c) << " ";
    return s.str();
}

template <typename T>
void convertFromHex(string s, T &x)
{
    char *xc = (char *)&x;
    istringstream is(s);
    for (char *c = xc; c < xc + sizeof(x); ++c)
    {
        int tmp;
        is >> hex >> tmp;
        *c = tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double a = 10;
    string as = convertToHex(a);
    cout << "a: " << as << endl;
    double b;
    convertFromHex(as, b);
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 40 
b: 10
```

Comment: Well, this would work listing the bytes but I'm worried that I might face problems with ordering on different systems.

Comment: @rsethc your requriments was not very clear. In this case probably you need boost::serialization http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is very very simple example with `boost::serializer` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). I am using `boost::archive::text_iarchive` and `boost::archive::text_oarchive`, but you can switch it to `boost::archive::binary_iarchive` and `boost::archive::binary_oarchive`. Should work.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double a = M_PI;
    string text;

    {
        ostringstream textStream;
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(textStream);
        oa << a;
        text = textStream.str();
    }
    cout << "a: " << text << endl;
    double b;
    {
        istringstream textStream(text);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(textStream);
        ia >> b;
    }
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 22 serialization::archive 9 3.1415926535897931
b: 3.14159
```